# Virus scanning a compressed file before vs after extracting

Tags: virus, compression, zip, extract, malware-detection

If I download a compressed file (i.e. a zip file, etc), does it make a difference if I:

a) virus scan it as is
**vs**.
b) virus scan after extracting it?

What are the differences/considerations if I am trying to detect any virus/bad-stuff in the files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scanning a compressed file can not show that the infected files are included within it because threats are hidden within the layers of the archive.

Extract the file to a folder implementing compression tool.

Scan the content of a folder. Follow the steps below:

Right-click the folder.

Select Scan with Protection software.

Protection software will scan the content of a folder and neutralize the virus.

Scan all content of a folder.

We suggest, to delete the compressed file to prevent the antivirus from identifying new threats in further scans.

Comment: I don't know why this was downvoted, it seems the most correct of the answers and I need to choose an answer apparently so this gets it.

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately, there is no difference.

All of the following is assuming your virus scanner can detect the virus.  Either the virus scanner will detect the virus inside the archive, or when the virus is eventually extracted.  Once that happens, the virus scanner will start its process of cleaning, quarantining, deleting the file, or whatever method is chosen.

It really comes down to what your virus scanner supports.  A virus scanner *cannot* detect a virus inside a compressed, archived, or encrypted file.  It has to decompress or unarchive the file to see its contents.  Some virus scanners have the ability to temporarily decompress these files on the fly and scan the contents.  However, that will only work if it is a known format to it.  Obviously, there are *many* compression algorithms and archive formats.  Then there is the question of whether it will look inside nested archives.

In the end, it doesnt matter, the virus scanner will either detect the virus when it is temporarily extracted (if supported) or when you manually extract the contents.

Comment: You contradict yourself multiple times here on whether it matters or not, it's too confusing to consider an answer. I think you are assuming the virus scanner is continuously scanning every file 24/7...? If that was true, what is the point of right clicking and performing a scan....or doing any full/partial scans of ur computer in general.